# Plane and Line Distance

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry

How it comes that `|D|` is the distance of a plane to the origin?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean the Hessian Normalform?

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I'm unsure, the book says: `point normal plane equation`.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think the variable from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html `D` isn't the same as what the book refers as `D`. I've added additional pictures from the book to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is the *normal vector* whose direction is perpendicular to the place, i.e. the same direction in which we measure *distance*. The *magnitude* of $n$ is not really important here. All we need is the magnitude of the *projection* of $p$ on $n$ which is given by the *absolute value* of the scalar product of $p$ and $n$, which is
$$p^{\prime}n=(4,0,0)^{\prime}(1,1,1)=4 \times 1 + 0 \times 1 + 0 \times 1=4$$
Hence the required distance. The picture presented there is helpful in understanding why the projection leads to the distance. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think my confusion is at the dot product of `p'n`, in trigonometric for the projection of `p onto n` would be `||po|| * cos(theta)` and yes that would be equal to `D`, but dot product is `||po|| * cos(theta) * ||n||`, shouldn't `n` be a unit vector?

Comment: Well the normal seems to be unit length.

Answer (score 1):

As distance can never be negative as in your case -4. So they take magnitude of D. So D changes to |D|.

Answer (score 0):

For the plane $$ax+by+cz=D$$ the distance from the origin to the plane is $$d=\left|\frac{D}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right|$$